# parse a date string

Tags: php, mysql, string, parsing, datetime

I have this string in a post variable

```
'03/21/2011'
```

I need to parse it via php and turn it into this format

```
'2011-03-21'
```

I am using php and i need this format so i can run this query

```
SELECT prospect as 'Prospect', company as 'Company', industry as 'Industry', created_at as 'Original Date Submitted', software as 'Software', warm_transfer as 'Warm Transfer', UserName as 'Sales Rep' FROM mercury_leads join user on UserID=user_id WHERE created_at BETWEEN '2011-01-01' AND '2011-03-22'
```

Comment: possible duplicate of [strtotime failing on mm-dd-yyyy hh:mm](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5133703/strtotime-failing-on-mm-dd-yyyy-hhmm)

Comment: and you can find a couple [dozen other duplicates by using the search function](http://stackoverflow.com/search?q=format+date+[php])

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you want to handle it in PHP, your best bet is to use the [`strtotime()`](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.strtotime.php) function which converts a string into a time that can then be manipulated with the [`date()`](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.date.php) function.

So you'd do something like:

```
$dateStr = date('Y-m-d', strtotime('03/21/2011'));
```

The nice thing about using `strtotime()` is that you don't have to worry about the exact format of the string you pass in.  As long as it's something semi-reasonable, it'll will convert it.

So it would handle **03/21/2011**, **3-21-2011**, **03-21-11** without any modifications or special cases.

Comment: Solution works great for this problem. However, be warned that it cannot parse d/m/Y which is a very reasonable format.

Comment: From the strtotime docs, it looks like it assumes m/d/y if / is used as a separator and d-m-y if - or . is used as the separator.

Comment: that sounds correct. Of course, that means it cannot actually parse `3-21-2011`. This is why I prefer `date_create_from_format` (because it could parse such a format if you asked it to), but obviously nothing can catch (e.g.) an accidental `d-m-Y` when `d <= 12`. Personally, I find `strtotime` more useful to parse phrases like "last monday."

Answer (score 1):

```
$items=explode('/','03/21/2011');
$time=mktime(0,0,0,$items[0],$items[1],$items[2]);
$isodate=date('Y-m-d',$time);
```

Answer (score 1):

You can parse it even from mysql

```
select str_to_date('03/21/2011','%m/%d/%Y')
```

Answer (score 1):

```
$date = '03/21/2011';
$timestamp = strtotime($date);
$sqlDate = date('Y-m-d', $timestamp);
```

That should do what you need.

[strtotime](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.strtotime.php)

[date](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.date.php)

Answer (score 1):

While there are many ways to do this, I think the easiest to understand and apply to all date conversions is:

```
$date = date_create_from_format('n/d/Y', $date)->format('Y-n-d');
```

It is explicit and you'll never have to wonder about m/d or d/m, etc.

Answer (score 1):

You can see it here

http://www.codegod.de/WebAppCodeGod/PHP-convert-string-to-date--AID597.aspx

Or use the Date class of PHP 5.3

Answer (score 0):

STR_TO_DATE(created_at, '%m/%d/%Y') as 'Original Date Submitted'.

Answer (score 0):

Answer 1:

You can use something like this

```
$dateStr = date('Y-m-d', strtotime($someDate));
```

Con

It is not great for code readability because it does not allow you to explicitly parse a certain format and make that obvious in the code. For instance your code will not be obvious to an outside programmer as to what format $someDate was in since strtotime parses multiple formats.

Pro

However if $someDate is subject to change and you want the code to continue to attempt to normalize various formats this is a great choice

Con

If you the data comes in a format that is not supported. For instance when trying to parse a date in a non-US date format meaning the month and day are switched but the format uses forward slashes (21/04/78) Dates in the m/d/y or d-m-y formats are disambiguated by looking at the separator between the various components: if the separator is a slash (/), then the American m/d/y is assumed; whereas if the separator is a dash (-) or a dot (.), then the European d-m-y format is assumed.

Answer 2:

To really make your code clear as to which date you are parsing and to validate that the data coming in as using the correct format, I would use date_create_from_format. Here is some code to help:

```
$server_date_str='06-10-2013 16:00:09';

$server_date_time = DateTime::createFromFormat('d-m-Y H:i:s',$server_date_str);

// check the format 

if ( !($server_date_time instanceof DateTime) ) {

  $error_array = DateTime::getLastErrors();

  throw new Exception( implode(" - ",$error_array['errors']) );

}

//convert DateTime object to Unix time stamp

$server_time = strtotime($server_date_time->format('d-m-Y H:i:s'));

//convert Unix timestamp to date string of the format 2012-10-21
$dateStr = date('Y-m-d', $server_time);
```

This example is explained in more full detail at this link:

http://boulderapps.co/parse-a-date-by-a-specific-date-format-in-php