# Formatting the date 2011-09-23T23:00:00 to look like 23.09.11

Tags: php, date

I'm hoping that this is a VERY simple question, but it's driving me insane!

Date formatting in PHP seems to require a timestamp, but all I have is `2011-09-23T23:00:00` and I'd like to turn that into `23.09.2011` - how do I do that?

Comment: http://www.php.net/manual/en/ref.datetime.php -- read the date & time function in the php manual (strtotime, date)

Comment: possible duplicate of [parse a date string](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5409401/parse-a-date-string)

Comment: It can be construed as duplication, although if you're going to merge them, perhaps a good title could be used to describe the sort of parsing we're doing. I can't think of a good one!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Using [DateTime / date_create](http://fr.php.net/manual/en/datetime.construct.php):

```
date_create('2011-09-23T23:00:00')->format('d.m.Y');
```

Using [strtotime](http://php.net/strtotime):

```
date('d.m.Y', strtotime('2011-09-23T23:00:00'));
```